Create a html button to open current local html file in editor
I made a home page, a page just containing dozens of (clickable) links, for my Firefox browser.
Until now, editing was done by finding this file in the file browser, right-click on it and select "open with Geany". I want to streamline this a bit, by adding an "edit" button on the page. This button should open Geany with the correct file displaying, ready to edit.
I have been searching the web, but did not find how to do this.
In a distant past, I dabbled a bit in Bash, where such a button was easy, something like:Geany path-to-file.
How can I do this in html/javascript? I need help creating this function.
I tried to get this button functioning, but did not succeed.
Gratefully,
Bert

In-browser code isn't able to invoke applications on the host machine.  (Imagine a world where any website you visit could execute any command it wants on your computer.)  You could perhaps write a browser extension which does this and invoke that extension on your page.  But overall it's likely that what you're trying to do won't save any effort from simply opening the file from your file system.  You're likely better off storing your data somewhere other than the file itself.  Local storage in the browser, a server-side web application with a database, etc.

Thank you David. That was really useful information!
